# What is the lowest resolution or fastest rescaling algorithm for Opencv images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, dataset

I'm looking for a image format with a very low resolution (e.g. 0-25 possible intensity levels) in Opencv for my real-time image processing

**The problem**

I'm developing a machine learning algorithm based on decision trees. This algorithm gets as input a dataset with multiple features where each feature can have a value from 0 to max. intensity level. As I am currently working with 8-bit Opencv formats this results in a range from 0 - 255 different levels. This resolution is way to fine due to I'm working with a very sparse dataset (i.e. it ends up in let's say 70% undefined cases). But if i rescale these values by e.g. 10 (so the range 0-25) the predictions are still alright and the number of undefined cases are going towards 0.

**My current solution**

I manually downscale every pixel with the help of loops by a particular value for the algorithm and afterwards upscale it again so it can be shown to the user. This takes too much time.

Would be nice if Opencv would provide a format with even smaller resolution, so I could work with these images right away and skip this preprocessing. If 8-bit greyscale images are already the smallest format, what is the fastest algorithm to easily rescale those ?

Comment: fastest to code would be just to multiply your mat images by a constant scale factor like 25.0/255.0 but probably there are faster (execution speed) solutions.

Comment: a lookup table may be really fast... see `cv::lut`. And yes, 8 bit is the smallest format

Comment: @Miki but a lookup table still needs to touch every pixel itself right? which is the(/my) main time loss

Comment: To modify each pixel value, you need to _touch_ each pixels... there's no shortcut. LUT can also be implemented in gpu or with SIMD instructions, so you should be ok...

Comment: opemCV's LUT is said to be very fast: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html